# Appium inspector - App doesn't reflect on the screen

Tags: ios, mobile, automation, automated-tests, appium

I managed to open the inspector appium normally, but it is not showing my application for I can inspect the elements.

Appium Version 1.4.13

[image: Appium screen]

shows this infinite loading!

Any idea?

Cheers,
Rafael

Comment: i have some questions for you as if you didnt provide much more info on question,1)are using real deviceor simulatot to test? 2)which app you are using like ios or android3 )have u checked debugging equals true in android mobile4)have you added debugmode =true in android app? 4)

Comment: if its on real device, try restarting device and adb, it should be okay

Answer (score 1):

@Rafael This occurs due to sync mismatch b/w app and ur mac, try restarting adb using `sudo adb kill-server && sudo adb start-server`

Comment: Worked fine. Thank you very much!